Joining Org Table Strings and Formula Results
I have an Org Mode table where I'm tracking draft and revision durations for various writing projects. It's set up like so:
| Title  | Draft Start | Draft End     | Draft Duration | Revision Start | Revision End | Revision Duration         |
|---------+------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+---------------------------|
| Project |<2024-01-05>| <2024-01-10>  |                |<2024-05-12>    |<2024-05-20>  |                           |

I know how to reference the fields to get the differences between the start and end dates: #+TBLFM: $4=$3-$2 for Draft Duration and #+TBLFM: $7=$6-$5 for Revision Duration. What I want is to append something like "days" or "d" to the end of that number, but I don't know how to do that. Things like $7='(concat((number-to-string ($6-$5)))) don't work. I've also tried putting the start and end dates in single columns as ranges like so:
| Title   | Draft Start--Draft End     | Draft Duration | Revision Start--Revision End  | Revision Duration         |
|---------+----------------------------+----------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------|
| Project |<2024-01-05>--<2024-01-10>  |                |<2024-05-12>--<2024-05-20>     |                           |

and using #TBLFM: $3='(org-evaluate-time-range), which gives the format I want, but doing the same with #+TBLFMT: $5='(org-evaluate-time-range) just repeats the calculation for the draft dates. There's no way to specify using the revision dates for the new calculation.
In short: How do I calculate the number of days between the dates, then put that number plus either "days" or "d" into the Durations fields?

[This is probably a bad answer, but it works in this particular case. I don't know if it will work under more general circumstances - my guess is probably not - and it uses low-level Calc code, thereby breaking all sorts of rules about code isolation. Unfortunately, I don't know of a better answer ATM. Maybe somebody else will be able to provide a better solution. If you don't get one, I'd suggest you post your question to the Org mode mailing list. Meanwhile, consider this answer to be a very dirty workaround.]
Try:
#+TBLFM: $4 = '(format "%d days" (calc-normalize (math-read-exprs (format "%s - %s" $3 $2))))

It basically constructs the string "<2024-01-10> - <2024-01-05>" and passes it to math-read-exprs which converts the dates to absolute and returns the form ((- (date 738895) (date 738890))) to calc-normalize, which carries out the subtraction, returning 5. That is then used in the "%d days" format to produce the string "5 days".
Alternatively, you might let Org and Calc do their thing unmolested and produce the result 5 as you are doing, but add an extra column to do your thing:
| Title   | Draft Start  | Draft End    | Draft Duration (work) | Draft Duration | Revision Start | Revision End | Revision Duration |
|---------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+-------------------|
| Project | <2024-01-05> | <2024-01-10> |                     5 | 5 days         | <2024-05-12>   | <2024-05-20> |                   |
#+TBLFM: $4 = $3 - $2 :: $5 = '(format "%s days" $4)

